# Json_Encode php last comma

Tags: php, mysql, json

For a school project I have to display database data as a valid json file.

```
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `csvdata`");

            echo "{ \"films\" : [";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $jsonResult = json_encode($row);
                echo $jsonResult;
                echo ",";   
            }
                echo "]}";
```

The output i get is:

```
{
    "films": [
        {
            "0": "Man on fire",
            "titel": "Man on fire",
            "1": "Actie",
            "genre": "Actie"
        },
        {
            "0": "Dumb and Dumberer",
            "titel": "Dumb and Dumberer",
            "1": "Comedy",
            "genre": "Comedy"
        },
        {
            "0": "DefQon 2014",
            "titel": "DefQon 2014",
            "1": "Muziek",
            "genre": "Muziek"
        },

    ]
}
```

Now my question is, how do I remove the last comma, I cannot find that. And all data tells the data 2 times, I also don't know how to avoid this.

Comment: AFAIK, the trailing comma in JSON arrays is ok, you should not care about it.

Comment: Collect the entire result in one PHP array, and then `json_encode` it all at once after it's built.

Comment: @Necto No, it's not OK. It is invalid and most libraries will fail on it - including PHP's `json_decode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `json_encode` handle the entire thing - build one array of data, and use `json_encode` on that.

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `csvdata`");

$response = array();
$response['films'] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $response['films'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Great, this helped!:) Now i just have the double data in, i don't know where it comes from. It is not in my database.. the "0" data and the "1" data

Comment: @Patrick Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array` to fix that or do `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`. The default behaviour is `MYSQLI_BOTH` which spits out both an associative and a numeric array.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this, is to not place a comma *after* writing every record, but instead *before* every record.

Then all you have to do, is add an if statement that doesn't output the comma for the very first row.